# Error when upload a photo tacken from the camera

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file-upload, webview

I am a beginner to android studio and  to mobile apps developing in general , however  i am still trying to learn .
so I have managed to build my first webview app to show a page  and a picture.I found a lot of useful resources that helped me to do so , but i am still facing a problem with uploading a photo taken from  the phone camera ( not from the gallery ) directly and upload to the server .

1- after I press on the brows button  the app prompts me whether to take the picture from the camera or from the gallery. ( Android version 9 )
2- when i upload a photo from the gallery the app works fine , **but when I use the camera to take a photo and upload startight away it does not work.  it gives me  the following error message although the photo name returned to the field path**

> -1_net::ERR_ACESS_DENIED

here is my onActivityResult    code

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;
            }
            Uri result = null;
            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    result = null;
                } else {
                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }

    } 
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        Uri[] results = null;      
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null || data.getData() == null) {
                // if there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }

        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;

    } // end of code for Lollipop only
}
```

-------and here is the openFileChooser ----------------

```
 public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
                mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

                try {
                    File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "DirectoryNameHere");

                    if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                        imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                    }

                    File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

                    mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file); // save to the private variable

                    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
                    // captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("image/*");

                    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.image_chooser));
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});

                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera Exception:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
      
I really appreciate your help
```

Comment: @blackapps I have removed the unnecessary code and  posted only onActivityResult, and openFileChooser.

Comment: You can remove the manifest file too. And all with `Intent i` as it is not used.

Comment: `imageStorageDir.mkdirs();` Check the return value. And if false display a Toast for the user telling so. And return. Dont continue then.

Comment: There is much to much code in onActivityResult. Its a mess. Put only code in it needed when you used the camera. And only for a build that gives problems.

Comment: Are you check read and write external storage and camera permission? Before call openFileChooser?

Comment: @adipurnama , I put that in the manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: i'm move coment to answer,hope that help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not enough just put in manifest,you must launch requet permission,

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
    Manifest.permission.REQUESTED_PERMISSION) ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
{
    // You can use the API that requires the permission
    openFileChooser();
}else{
    requestPermissions(this,new String[] { 
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA},100
        );
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResults(
    int requestCode, String[] permissions,int[] grantResults) 
    {
    if (requestCode==100 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        openFileChooser();
    }else{
        //not grant show toas or dialog
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for my problem .
after debuging I have realised that the path of the images folder that I put in the createImageFile() is not exists and not created  , so i replaced my createImageFile() with the following code and it worked with me

```
String currentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Thank you all for your help .